# pyinstaller runtime error when importing modules

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyinstaller

I am having issues getting pyinstaller to work with my project. I am using a conda environment to install all my dependencies. As soon as I import any installed dependencies I get an unhandled win32 exception:
"A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program."

[image: error_message]

I already tried to add the site-packages explicitly such as:

```
pyinstaller --debug=all --paths C:\miniconda3\envs\my_env\Lib\site-packages main.py
```

But same error. I don't even know how to start debugging this. There are no errors or warnings during the build process.

Output when running exe in cmd:

```
[10748] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[10748] LOADER: executable is E:\git\ssb\dist\main\main.exe
[10748] LOADER: homepath is E:\git\ssb\dist\main
[10748] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[10748] LOADER: archivename is E:\git\ssb\dist\main\main.exe
[10748] LOADER: Cookie found at offset 0x4C49F
[10748] LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
[10748] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(E:\git\ssb\dist\main)
[10748] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.      
[10748] LOADER: Python library: E:\git\ssb\dist\main\python37.dll
[10748] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[10748] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[10748] LOADER: sys.prefix is E:\git\ssb\dist\main
[10748] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip;E:\git\ssb\dist\main\lib-dynload;E:\git\ssb\dist\main
[10748] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[10748] LOADER: Runtime option: v
[10748] LOADER: Initializing python
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>    
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'nt' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>     
import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'winreg' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# zipimport: found 150 names in 'E:\\git\\ssb\\dist\\main\\base_library.zip'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import codecs # loaded from Zip E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip\codecs.pyc
import encodings.aliases # loaded from Zip E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip\encodings\aliases.pyc
import encodings # loaded from Zip E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip\encodings\__init__.pyc
import encodings.utf_8 # loaded from Zip E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip\encodings\utf_8.pyc
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import encodings.latin_1 # loaded from Zip E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip\encodings\latin_1.pyc
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import abc # loaded from Zip E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip\abc.pyc
import io # loaded from Zip E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip\io.pyc
[10748] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[10748] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip;E:\git\ssb\dist\main\lib-dynload;E:\git\ssb\dist\main
[10748] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[10748] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[10748] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[10748] LOADER: extracted struct
[10748] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for struct...
import '_struct' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
[10748] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
[10748] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod01_os_path...
[10748] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
[10748] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod02_archive...
import 'zlib' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
[10748] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
[10748] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod03_importers...
[10748] LOADER: extracted pyimod04_ctypes
[10748] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for pyimod04_ctypes...
[10748] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[10748] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[10748] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
# PyInstaller: FrozenImporter(E:\git\ssb\dist\main\main.exe?311993)
# os not found in PYZ
# code object from 'E:\\git\\ssb\\dist\\main\\os.pyc'
# stat not found in PYZ
# code object from 'E:\\git\\ssb\\dist\\main\\stat.pyc'
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x000002C9385DF2E8>
# ntpath not found in PYZ
# code object from 'E:\\git\\ssb\\dist\\main\\ntpath.pyc'
# genericpath not found in PYZ
# code object from 'E:\\git\\ssb\\dist\\main\\genericpath.pyc'
import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x000002C9385E7198>
import 'ntpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x000002C9385DF978>
# _collections_abc not found in PYZ
import _collections_abc # loaded from Zip E:\git\ssb\dist\main\base_library.zip\_collections_abc.pyc
import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x000002C9385C62E8>
# ctypes not found in PYZ
# code object from 'E:\\git\\ssb\\dist\\main\\ctypes\\__init__.pyc'
# _ctypes not found in PYZ
```

I am not sure the "not found" stuff is of any concern. It also shows up when I remove all `imports` to modules which then runs without the crash. I dont belive it is any issue related to not found modules as I get something like this for all modules during building:

```
10178 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\miniconda3\\envs\\ssb\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
```

Comment: To start debugging - open cmd and run the exe from there. Most likely there are modules that you need to specify as hidden imports.

Comment: Had to add --debug=all for the output, thx for the hint. Added debug, output but not much help : (